# How Can i count total number of update row at ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE MySQ -php

Tags: mysql, count, duplicates, insert-update

```
$sqlins = "INSERT INTO table1 (tbv1,tbv2)
          values ('$tb1','$tbv2') on duplicate key update tbv2 = '$tbv2'";

// here tbv1 uniq index
```

How Can i count total number of update row at `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` MySQL  query from php script

Comment: I'd say it's always 1. If it gets inserted its 1 and if the unique constraint matches it's also just 1.

Answer (score 0):

Get the number of affected rows. It will count 1 row for every normal `INSERT`, 2 rows for every `INSERT` that was turned into an `UPDATE`. So subtract the number of affected rows from the number of rows you listed in the `INSERT` statement, that will be the number of updated rows.

I'm not sure if this is documented anywhere, I just discovered it by doing `INSERT` statements by hand and viewing the results:

```
mysql> select * from barmar_test3;
+----+------+
| id | val  |
+----+------+
|  1 | dup  |
|  2 | xyz  |
|  6 | abc  |
+----+------+

mysql> insert into barmar_test3 values (2, 'yz') on duplicate key update val = values(val);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```